# Formatting in Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c++, windows, formatting, codeblocks

Is there a way of doing the following formatting things automatically in Code::Blocks? They seem automatic in Visual studio, and I've gotten used to them.

1. Replace things like `int a=b;` with `int a = b;`
2. Same for the equality operators and `&&` and `||` in conditionals
3. Space after `;`s in for loops
4. Have it not mess up the `<=` and `>=` operators (when doing the
   replacement).

I want it to be done automatically as I type (when I complete a statement), neither by pressing a `key combination` after each line nor by a `regex` or a `plugin` afterwards by processing my source code files. I believe that the inbuilt `Source Formatter` doesn't do this as I type.
If not possible please suggest a C++ ide for Windows (lighter than Visual Studio) for the same.

Comment: With practice using the space bar becomes second nature, you don't even notice you're doing it.

Comment: @Galik Yes, you are right but is there a way to do so automatically?